# What are some self-hosted alternatives to Graphhopper's Geocoding API?

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, software-recommendations, routing, graphhopper

I have a self-hosted instance of Graphhopper. However, it doesn't come with autocomplete like the [web demo](https://graphhopper.com/maps/); from doing some searching, it looks like the autocomplete comes from the Geocoding API, which is a part of GH's Directions API. GH offers the Directions API for business use only, with no self-hosting option available. Are there any geocoding APIs that can:

1. Integrate with OSM data?
2. Have a self-hosted option? and
3. Integrate with Graphhopper, without too much hair-pulling?

If there are self-hosted alternatives for the other components of the overarching Directions API (Routing API, Map Match API, etc.), so much the better.

Comment: See the overview image at the bottom of https://www.graphhopper.com/open-source/

Answer (score 1):

All known geocoding search engines that can deal with OSM based data should be listed at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines

Maybe some of those solutions have an API like the one you mentioned or that fits to your needs.

Are you looking for a solution like http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/ where you can choose between several routing engines and some geocoding API including Nominatim?